# Set page item with value from interactive grid column when clicking on the grid region

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I'm using apex 22.1. I'm trying to set a page field with a value from interactive grid column on the row I'm currently on, and it needs to change if I change the row I'm on.

This is what I have tried. I have assigned static id to the grid "IG_GRID". One of the columns on the grid is named "OS_TIP". I have a page item named "P660_LOV_OS_TIP".
I want to click on the IG region, on a row, and when I do that, I want the item P660_LOV_OS_TIP to be populated with the value from column OS_TIP on the row I'm on.
What I have tried is creating dynamic action on IG region with event "Selection change [Interactive grid]". I then created true action "set value", set type "Javascript expression".
I used this code for js:

```
apex.region("IG_GRID").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews").grid.model.getValue($v("CURRENT_ROW_INDEX"), "OS_TIP")
```

Under affected items selection type I chose "Item's", under items I set my item "P660_LOV_OS_TIP".
But when I click anywhere on the grid, nothing happens, my page item is not set with a value.
If I open console and enter the JS code above, I get "unedfined" response.
What am I doing wrong? How can I set this page item by selecting a IG row.
I'm not good with javascript, so error is probably there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to set a page item `P148_SELECTED_FIRST` to the value of the column "ENAME" on select of the row. The IG is on the EMP table of the EMP/DEPT sample dataset.

Create a dynamic action on "Selection Change [Interactive Grid]". Add a true action of type "Execute Javascript Code" with source:

```
const model = this.data.model,
    records = this.data.selectedRecords;
let values = records.map( r => model.getValue( r, "ENAME" ) ); 

apex.item( "P148_SELECTED_FIRST" ).setValue( values[0] );
```

Note the `values` is an array because - if the checkbox is visible - a user can select multiple records. The code above sets the page item to the first value of the array.

--Update--

An interactive grid column of type "Popup LOV" has 2 attributes: a display value and a value. This can be seen in the console if you output the javascript variable in the console:

[image]

Just pick the attribute you need. To set the display value:

```
apex.item( "P148_SELECTED_FIRST" ).setValue( values[0].d );
```

or selected value

```
apex.item( "P148_SELECTED_FIRST" ).setValue( values[0].v );
```

Comment: When I used it on text column on IG, it worked. But this OS_TIP column is pop-up lov, and when I used the code with that column, my item was showing [object Object] as value.

Comment: OK, .v works. Can I also submit this item without submitting the page, so it can be used as an input parameter for a shared component list of values?

Comment: For a shared component that might be hard, there is no way to submit an item to the session for a shared component. It's definitely possible for a list of values that is not a shared component: add a dynamic action on change of the page item you're setting and make sure that the list of values is cascading